# Pandas, stack some columns, unstack some others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Pandas tidy data, spread variables from one column, gather from another

## My Problem

I need to turn the dataframe below into a `tidy` format, where each row will be a unique `['GEOG_CODE','COUNTRY']` - `'YEAR'` pairing, and there are two variables, defined by `Group1`.

Using Hadley Wickham's notation for [tidy data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html):

- The **observations** are defined by the Location-Time pairings.
- The **variables** are defined by the column `Group1`
- The **values** are currently stored for different Years in columns `['2016'  '2017'  '2018']`.

[image: Tidy Data Semantics]

In R I would want to:

- `gather` the values from the columns `['2016'  '2017'  '2018']`.
- `spread` the values from `Group1`.
- see [Garrett Grolemund's explanation here](http://garrettgman.github.io/tidying/)

For my problem:

- *Location* is defined by the `['GEOG_CODE','COUNTRY']`.
- *Values* at different times are defined in the columns `['2016'  '2017'  '2018']`.
- *Variables* are defined by `Group1 == A` or `Group1 == B`.

I want to have each row as a Location-Time pair, with two variables. One for `Group1 = A`, one for `Group1 = B`

## I have this

```py
toy_data = {
    'GEOG_CODE':['123','234','567','901'],
    'COUNTRY':['England' for _ in range(4)],
    'Group1':['A','A','B','B'],
    '2016':np.arange(0,4),
    '2017':np.arange(0,4),
    '2018':np.arange(0,4),
}
in_df = pd.DataFrame(toy_data)
in_df

Out[]:
GEOG_CODE  COUNTRY Group1  2016  2017  2018
0       123  England      A     0     0     0
1       234  England      A     1     1     1
2       567  England      B     2     2     2
3       901  England      B     3     3     3
```

## I want this

So I want the output to look like the dataframe below with columns for each of the values in `'Group1'`

```py
outcome_data = {
    'GEOG_CODE': np.tile(['123','234','567','901'],3),
    'COUNTRY':['England' for _ in range(4*3)],
    'year':np.tile([2016,2017,2018],4),
    'low_A':np.tile(np.arange(0,4),3),
    'low_B':np.tile(np.arange(0,4),3),
}

out = pd.DataFrame(outcome_data)
out

Out[]:
GEOG_CODE  COUNTRY  year  low_A  low_B
0        123  England  2016      0      0
1        234  England  2017      1      1
2        567  England  2018      2      2
3        901  England  2016      3      3
4        123  England  2017      0      0
5        234  England  2018      1      1
6        567  England  2016      2      2
7        901  England  2017      3      3
8        123  England  2018      0      0
9        234  England  2016      1      1
10       567  England  2017      2      2
11       901  England  2018      3      3
```

## I tried `df.melt()`

I managed to get the data half of the way by using the melt functionality but then I don't know how to turn the groups into rows.

```py
id_vars = ['GEOG_CODE', 'COUNTRY', 'Group1']
value_vars = ['2016', '2017', '2018']
var_name = 'Year'
value_name = 'low_Value'

melt = in_df.melt(id_vars=id_vars,value_vars=value_vars,var_name=var_name, value_name=value_name)
melt

Out[]:
GEOG_CODE  COUNTRY Group1  Year  low_Value
0        123  England      A  2016          0
1        234  England      A  2016          1
2        567  England      B  2016          2
3        901  England      B  2016          3
4        123  England      A  2017          0
5        234  England      A  2017          1
6        567  England      B  2017          2
7        901  England      B  2017          3
8        123  England      A  2018          0
9        234  England      A  2018          1
10       567  England      B  2018          2
11       901  England      B  2018          3
```

Comment: have you looked in to the `pd.wide_to_long` function?

Comment: Yes but I can't see how that can help me directly because the values for `stubnames` are not columns, they're values in the column `Group1`

Comment: Why do you have a "low_C" and where does it come from?

Comment: sorry that was a poor edit, I tried to simplify the code but forgot to remove the extra column! Thankyou

Comment: @TommyLees Let me know if the answer below wasn't what you're looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You are 100% a genius. Thank you for editing my title last night too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `stack` instead of `melt`:

```
(df.set_index(['GEOG_CODE', 'COUNTRY', 'Group1'])
   .stack()
   .unstack(-2)
   .ffill(axis=1)
   .bfill(axis=1, downcast='infer')
   .add_prefix('low_')
   .reset_index()
   .rename({'level_2': 'year'}, axis=1))

Group1 GEOG_CODE  COUNTRY  year  low_A  low_B
0            123  England  2016      0      0
1            123  England  2017      0      0
2            123  England  2018      0      0
3            234  England  2016      1      1
4            234  England  2017      1      1
5            234  England  2018      1      1
6            567  England  2016      2      2
7            567  England  2017      2      2
8            567  England  2018      2      2
9            901  England  2016      3      3
10           901  England  2017      3      3
11           901  England  2018      3      3
```

Comment: Could you help me interpret what the different lines do? Unfortunately the code doesn't work removing a line at a time because: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

Comment: @TommyLees This works under the assumption that each `['GEOG_CODE', 'COUNTRY', 'Group1']` combination is unique. The idea is to stack all the columns, while unstacking "Group1". Perhaps you can try `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['GEOG_CODE', 'COUNTRY', 'Group1'])` before running this.

Comment: If i turn it into a function with a function docstring, can I add it to your answer? Im happy to post as a new answer but don't want to take any of the credit. I just think it might be useful to others (& future me) who want to do something similar.

Comment: @TommyLees Sure, feel free to propose an edit at the bottom of my answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: I am still having problems with getting the code to work with a real problem. The issue that I do have non-unique combinations. Because `['COUNTRY','AREA CODE']` have multiple `Group1` values over many timesteps. Can I edit the question or should i ask a new question?

Comment: @TommyLees best thing imo would be to open a new question, mention it's a follow up to this and explain what's wrong.